How To Hard Surface Model A Tron: Legacy 2nd Gen Light Cycle?
This has been surprisingly difficult for me to approach, and it is showing the cracks in my modeling abilities. I have been learning Blender since 2008, but I've never dived deep into hard surface modeling because the precision and intricate cutting and details have seemed daunting to me. I wish to overcome this by making this project, but I'm having trouble determining how to begin.
What I want to make is Flynn's Light Cycle from Tron: Legacy. It's an updated version of the original Tron Light Cycle design. I'm using the blueprint below as reference. What I'm stumbling with is trying to nail down how to begin modeling the primary shape, starting at the front "wheel". The shape flows into the body, and it is spherical with what I would determine to be boolean cuts on the sides, another boolean for the wheel-center hole, and then the rest of the details are inset cuts? Also, what is the method for creating panel cuts to make line cuts to make an object appear to be separate pieces?
I'm having trouble figuring out how to make that initial round shape (Can't say I'm fully confident in knowing the rest either), and then beyond that shape, having it flow into the rest of the body. Could this be a re-mesh thing, something else I don't really have experience working with? This might be too much of a challenge for me to tackle with my knowledge and skill-set, but I am always eager to learn and better educate myself! Typically I would be able to follow a tutorial to make something complex like this, but surprisingly there aren't any topics or videos covering this particular model. I'm not even sure how much can really be explained compared to how much I should really have a formal education in this type of thing. Thank you for your continued support and patience.



Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Draw the profile:

Extrude to give it thickness, push some edges, extrude some faces, etc:

